# Pandas: How to merge cells in the dataframe from a specific column using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to remove the duplicated names from the cells and merge them. This dataframe is generated after concatenating multiple dataframes.

My dataframe as under:

```
|   | Customer ID | Category      | VALUE   |
| -:|:----------- |:------------- | -------:|
| 0 | GETO90      | Baby Sets     |  1090.0 |
| 1 | GETO90      | Girls Dresses |  5357.0 |
| 2 | GETO90      | Girls Jumpers |  2823.0 |
| 3 | SETO90      | Girls Top     |  3398.0 |
| 4 | SETO90      | Shorts        |  7590.0 |
| 5 | SETO90      | Shorts        |  7590.0 |
| 6 | RETO90      | Pants         |  6590.0 |
| 7 | RETO90      | Pants         |  6590.0 |
| 8 | RETO90      | Jeans         |  8590.0 |
| 9 | YETO90      | Jeans         |  9590.0 |
| 10| YETO90      | Jeans         |  2590.0 |
```

I want to merge the first column and the expected dataframe is mentioned below:

```
|   | Customer ID | Category      | VALUE   |
| -:|:----------- |:------------- | -------:|
| 0 | GETO90      | Baby Sets     |  1090.0 |
| 1 |             | Girls Dresses |  5357.0 |
| 2 |             | Girls Jumpers |  2823.0 |
| 3 | SETO90      | Girls Top     |  3398.0 |
| 4 |             | Shorts        |  7590.0 |
| 5 |             | Shorts        |  7590.0 |
| 6 | RETO90      | Pants         |  6590.0 |
| 7 |             | Pants         |  6590.0 |
| 8 |             | Jeans         |  8590.0 |
| 9 | YETO90      | Jeans         |  9590.0 |
| 10|             | Jeans         |  2590.0 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `duplicated` with `loc`:

```
df.loc[df.duplicated('Customer ID'), 'Customer ID'] = ''
```